# Yii: relation through one table to another

Tags: activerecord, yii, relation

I have such scheme of tables:
[image]

My task is to get the event's description string from third table via relations, which look so:

```
'dates'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CalendarDates', '', 
                                "on" => '"t"."CalendarDateId"="dates"."calendar_date_id"'),

'events'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CalendarDayEvents', '', 
                                "on" => '"dates"."list_events" = "events"."date_id"')
```

So, I consider, that getting `dates`from first relation

```
$UserCalendar =  CalendarsUsers::model()->
                    with(array('dates','events'))->
                    find('user_id =:user_id', array(':user_id'=> $userId));
```

I would get the such scheme

```
Date as Dates
```

and list of events fron third table, which is linked to every `Date`

But using the relation, which is presented above, I'm getting "parallel" relation, where dates and events are "parallel", so I can't write code like this:

```
<?php foreach ($calendar->dates as $day): ?>

       <b>Date:</b> <?php echo($day->date_event); ?> <br>
       <i>Event:</i> 
            <?php foreach ($day as $event): ?>
                <?php echo($event->event_description); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <br/>        
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which returns me error as expected.

Comment: $day is a object that extends CActiveRecord, right? Why are you using it as an array inside the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion try the following modification. 
As I do not know your accurate tables name, I call them `first`, `second` and `third` relatively.

In your `first` model, put the following relation:

```
'second' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SECOND_TABLE_MODEL', 'FIRST_TABLE_KEY_WHICH_IS_RELATED_TO_SECOND')
```

In your `second` model, put the following relation:

```
'third' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'THIRD_TABLE_MODEL', 'SECOND_TABLE_KEY_WHICH_IS_RELATED_TO_THIRD')
```

now, let's skip the `third` table relations. I consider you only want to access the `description` in `third` table.
Then, if you do like bellow:

```
$firstRecords=First::model()->findAll();
```

You have all records from your `First` table. You do not need to use `with` here. to access the `second` table data, which is related to `first` table you can do like below:

```
foreach($firstRecords as $fr){
    //$fr->second->ATTRIBUTE_NAME
}
```

Finally, if you want to access the `description` from `third` table you can do like bellow:

```
foreach($firstRecords as $fr){
    $second=$first->second;
    foreach($second->third as $st){
       //$st->description
    }
}
```

I hope it help

Comment: Hm, when I try to use this code $fr->second->ATTRIBUTE_NAME (mine is 

foreach ($firstRecords as $record) {
     var_dump($record->dates->date_event);
   
 };
)
it returns me NULLs.

Comment: dates is second model

Comment: Did you put the correct relation in your first model's relation method?

Comment: Yes, you right , it was my mistake. returns OK, trying futher.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can use CVarDumper::dump($variable,6789,true) instead of var_dump, which is really powerful.

Comment: Now, when I try to get access to 'third' the follow SQL is executed SELECT "events"."id" AS "t1_c0", "events"."date_id" AS "t1_c1", "events"."event_description" AS "t1_c2" FROM "CalendarDayEvents" "events" WHERE ("events"."date_id"=4)
but date_id form WHERE clause has value which is not correct, must be values from list_events of 'second' table

Comment: yes, scheme is correct and works, instead of last WHERE clause

Comment: Please check your table's data to be sure about data. I thing it is impossible to see an incorrect value